# How do I trigger and if statement with a user input stored in a list?

Tags: python

So I am trying to make code in python to further my understanding of the language, and partially for fun :), anyway I am trying to make a program that clocks in and out employees. But I am stuck as when I input a username and password to login to the service it doesn't know the pre-set 'admin' login details.
Here is my code: main parts are starred

```
**username = ['Admin']
password = ['admin']**

def login():
    print()
    print("Welcome to the Enterprise clock in and clock out system")
    print()
    un = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print()
    pw = input("And password: ")
    **for i in username and password:
            if un == username and pw == password:
                main()**
    else:
        print()
        print("The username or password was incorrect")
        login()

def main():
    print("Welcome to Enterprise")
    print()
    print("What would you like to do?\n")
    ch = input("Choice: ")
    print()
    print("1 - Clock in")
    print("2 - Clock in")
    print("3 - Add new employee")

login()
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

`username` and `password` are *lists*, and `un` and `pw` are *strings*, but you're trying to compare them, which doesn't make sense.

You could try this instead:

```
for pair in zip(username, password):
    if (un, pw) == pair: main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a better approach here would be to use a dict instead of lists.
Instead of:

```
username = ['Admin']
password = ['admin']
```

Do something like:

```
creds = {'Admin':'admin'}
```

This way you won't need a loop, you can just check:

```
if creds.has_key(un) and creds[un] == pw:
    #rest of code
```

The `has_key` method is important because if you try to access a key that doesn't exist it will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have put `username` and `password` into lists. So comparing an input, which is string by default, together with list, won't be the same.

If you put this into your idle:

```
var1 = ["Admin"]
var2 = "Admin"
var1 == var2
False
```

But you could also index the list too:

```
var1[0] == var2
True
```